# How to put different D3.js scripts on the same page without overlapping?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am using D3.js to showcase my data. However, I am unable to get two different objects to not overlap. For example, the code below shows a line graph and a bar graph. I am using code from https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery for this example to show my issue. The line graph code is from https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245. The bar graph code is from https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304. I tried using  as shown in this example http://www.d3noob.org/2013/07/arranging-more-than-one-d3js-graph-on.html, but it did not work. I also made sure they both used the same version of d3.js. The data is from two tsv files that are on the links above for the line and bar graph. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}

</style>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>


<div id="lineg"></div>
<div id="barg"></div>
<lineg width="960" height="500"></lineg>
<barg width="960" height="500"></barg>
<script>

var svga = d3.select("#lineg"),
    margina = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    widtha = +svga.attr("width") - margina.left - margina.right,
    heighta = +svga.attr("height") - margina.top - margina.bottom;

var xa = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, widtha]).padding(0.1),
    ya = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([heighta, 0]);

var ga = svga.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margina.left + "," + margina.top +     ")");

d3.tsv("bardata.tsv", function(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  xa.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  ya.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  ga.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + heighta + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(xa));

  ga.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(ya).ticks(10, "%"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  ga.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return xa(d.letter); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return ya(d.frequency); })
      .attr("width", xa.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return heighta - ya(d.frequency); });
});

</script>


<script>

var svgb = d3.select("barg"),
    marginb = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    widthb = +svgb.attr("width") - marginb.left - marginb.right,
    heightb = +svgb.attr("height") - marginb.top - marginb.bottom,
    gb = svgb.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + marginb.left +    "," + marginb.top + ")");

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

var xb = d3.scaleTime()
    .rangeRound([0, widthb]);

var yb = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([heightb, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xb(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return yb(d.close); });

d3.tsv("linedata.tsv", function(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  xb.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  yb.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  gb.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + heightb + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(xb))
    .select(".domain")
      .remove();

  gb.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(yb))
    .append("text")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  gb.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `barg` and `lineg` are just divs:

```
<div id="lineg"></div>
<div id="barg"></div>
```

Instead of that, they should be SVG elements, like this:

```
<svg id="barg" width="960" height="500"></svg>
<svg id="lineg" width="960" height="500"></svg>
```

Or, alternatively, append an SVG in your selection:

```
var svga = d3.select("#lineg").append("svg");
var svgb = d3.select("#barg").append("svg");
```

However, in that case, you cannot use the getters to get the width and height of the SVGs.

Finally, there is no HTML tag named `<lineg>` or `<barg>`.

Comment: I made the change with the svg tags so I could include width and height; however, it only shows the bar graph now. If I switch the order of the bar and line graph, then only the line graph will show. So basically, the second graph shows only.

Comment: You have other problem somewhere, because it's working just fine for me: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/210afe80be25f2ca436f67882976f165/18a3f4792ed4b2a0ef6790c191568e215ef009c5. If you click "open" you'll see this: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/raw/210afe80be25f2ca436f67882976f165/18a3f4792ed4b2a0ef6790c191568e215ef009c5/.

Comment: never mind, only the line graph doesn't show. I'll try and see if there are any discrepancies in my code

Comment: Well, as you can see, my solution works. Also, I'm seeing that you never accepted an answer here at S.O. If you don't accept your working answers users simply stop answering your questions (I mean I do).

Comment: Yeah my issue was a missing "#" symbol. In terms of "accepting answers", I don't know what you mean. I only asked a few questions so I didn't know there was an "accepting answers portion".

Comment: Is that green check the "accepting answers" portion?

Comment: @Sam Yes, that's the green tick. You don't *need* to accept an answer if you don't want to, but if an answer fixes your problem it's a good policy accepting it, so other users can get this information. Also, with your new reputation, you can upvote an answer if you think it is useful and well written or downvote an answer if you think that it's wrong and not useful (the arrows pointing up and down).